# Get all occurrences of whatever is after a character

Tags: php, string

How can I get all occurences of whatever is after a string and have it returned in an array
suppose I have the following

```
$text = 'Hello !Jack, How is !Angela? What is !Ahmad93 doing?';
```

I need to get Jack, Angela and Ahmad93 in an array, is there anyway to do this?

Comment: It looks like all those "names" start with an exclamation mark,right? Have a look at regex101.com and try to create a regex for it :) That should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`/!([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g`](http://regex101.com/r/dN2nN4)

**My assumptions:**

- All the names start with an Exclamation mark (!)
- All names only consist of the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] (alphanumeric)

You could change it to [`/!(\w+)/g`](http://regex101.com/r/pQ3hA7) though, but that will also match an underscore, but I'm not sure if that is what you want.

```
preg_match_all('/!(\w+)/', $string, $matches);
$uniqueNames = array_unique($matches[1]);
```

*Note: since I use preg_match_all I don't need the /g modifier*

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$text = 'Hello !Jack, How is !Angela? What is !Ahmad93 doing?';
preg_match_all("/!([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/", $text, $pat_array);
print_r($pat_array[1]); //Array ( [0] => Jack [1] => Angela [2] => Ahmad93 )
```